# How to make "form_for" use "remote => true" based on condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that should use "remote => true" when it's updating a record, but not when creating a new one.

I tried:

```
<%= form_for position position.new_record? ? (, :remote => true do) |p| %>
```

syntax error...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To fix your example:

```
<%= form_for position, (position.new_record? ? {} : {:remote => true}) do |p| %>
```

But to make it a bit nicer you could do this:

```
<%= form_for position, :remote => position.new_record? do |p| %>
```

Comment: Thank you. The second example is very elegant :)